# Extracting data from a multi-line session/job logs with awk with overlapping lines

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Suppose I have got a large log file, similar to this:

```
[2016-11-11 16:41:06.062] <sid:111> start1
[2016-11-11 16:41:06.062] <sid:111> op <555>
[2016-11-11 16:41:06.063] <sid:111> op <666>
[2016-11-11 16:41:07.124] <sid:222> start1
[2016-11-11 16:41:07.125] <sid:111> end
[2016-11-11 16:41:07.123] <sid:222> op <777>
[2016-11-11 16:41:08.333] <sid:333> start2
[2016-11-11 16:41:08.352] <sid:333> op <888>
[2016-11-11 16:41:08.352] <sid:333> op <999>
[2016-11-11 16:41:09.062] <sid:333> end
[2016-11-11 16:41:09.100] <sid:222> op <222>
[2016-11-11 16:41:09.100] <sid:222> op <333>
[2016-11-11 16:41:09.100] <sid:222> end
```

And suppose I need to know what are the `operation` number for each session that starts with `start1`:

```
<sid:111> <555>
<sid:111> <666>
<sid:222> <777>
<sid:222> <222>
<sid:222> <333>
```

How can I do that with `awk` (or anything else), when there is high chance that concurrent sessions are being executed in parallel and that lines are not all together.

I've tried with the following `awk` script:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        seen_start = 0;
        seen_end = 1;
    }
    !seen_start && seen_end && $0 ~ /start1/ {
        match($0, "(<sid:[a-f0-9]+>) start1", m);
        sid = m[1];
        seen_start = 1;
        seen_end = 0;
    }
    seen_start && !seen_end && $0 ~ sid && $0 ~ /op/ {
        match($0, "op (<[0-9]+>)", m);
        print sid, m[1];
    }
    seen_start && !seen_end && $0 ~ sid && $0 ~ /end/ {
        seen_start = 0;
        seen_end = 1;
    }
' test
```

But, I miss the sessions starting in the middle of another one.

```
<sid:111> <555>
<sid:111> <666>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my %hash;
while (<>) {
    if (/(<sid:[a-f0-9]+>) start1/) {
        $hash{$1} = 1;
    }
    elsif (/(<sid:[a-f0-9]+>) op (<[0-9]+>)/) {
        if (exists $hash{$1}) {
            print "$1 $2\n";
        }
    }
    elsif (/(<sid:[a-f0-9]+>) end/) {
        if (exists $hash{$1}) {
            delete $hash{$1};
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

awk one-liner

```
awk -F '[:<>]' '/start1/ {a[$5]; next} /end/ {delete a[$5]; next} /op/ && $5 in a {print $5, $7}' test
```

**Explanation**

```
awk -F '[:<>]' '                  # Split on either :, < or >
    /start1/ {a[$5]; next}        # Note that the session has started
    /end/ {delete a[$5]; next}    # note session ended
    /op/ && $5 in a {             # print if session has started
        print $5, $7
    }
'
```